# dompdf - image output

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I'm using the `dompdf` library to create PDFs from HTML.

I am having a problem rendering images, as they seem to be appearing as red crosses.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html = '<div><img src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/images/image1.jpg" /><div>';

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("A4");
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
$filename = date('dmYHis') . '-lowres.pdf';

file_put_contents('/uploads/pdfs/low-res/' . $filename, $output);
```

This creates the PDF, but it doesn't seem to find the image.

I've tried to have just `<img src="/uploads/images/imag1.jpg" />`, but this also renders the image as a red cross.

I'm using the 0.6.0beta3 version of DomPDF

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seemed having a path such as the full URL doesn't work.

Neither does `<img src="/uploads/images..."` />`

I changed the path to be `<img src="uploads/images..." />` which seemed to work

Comment: The full URL should work, so long as dompdf has read/write access to the directory specified by DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR, and so long as DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE is set to true. Beyond that, whether or not dompdf will find your image depends on a number of factors, namely how you load the document and the path used.